# Basic Authentication Filter and authentication entry point not actually used from spring oauth2 token request

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have implemented resource owner flow with spring oauth2 based on spring's sparklr sample application and a couple of samples I found online. I tested the token request part with curl like this in order to provide both client and user credentials:

```
curl -v --data "username=user1&password=user1&client_id=client1&client_secret=client1&grant_type=password" -X POST "http://localhost:8080/samplerestspringoauth2/oauth/token"
```

and it works correctly, however I have made the following observation:

Although according to the examples I saw, I make use of the BasicAuthentication filter, this is not really used in the security process. Since the token request does not contain an Authentication header, the BasicAuthentication filter just skips doing any checks. ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter and authentication-server are the only ones performing security checks during the token request.  After noticing this and verifying it via debugging, I tried to remove completely the following part:

> `<http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />`

from the configuration. But then I got the warning:

> "No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established. Please make sure
>   you have a login mechanism configured through   the namespace (such as
>   form-login) or specify a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint with the
>   'entry-point-ref' attribute".

As a next step, I added the entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint in the http namespace, and got rid of the warning. I tested the app and played correctly.

However, in addition to the above, I have also made the following observation during debugging:
The ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter, contains its own OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint entry point inside a private variable, and uses that when failing due to wrong client credentials.
Therefore, it does not matter what entry point I specify either in the basic filter, or in the http namespace. At the end ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter will use its own private OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint.
To summarize my conclusions seem to be the following:

- The basic filter is not used and can be removed, if we specify the
  endpoint in the http namespace instead.
- Specifying either a basic
  filter,or an endpoint in http namespace is needed only for the
  compiler to stop the warning. They have no practical use, and the
  endpoint used is hardcoded inside
  ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter.

Below I put the http and endpoint configuration for the token request for your reference. I skip the rest of configuration for keeping the post easy to read:

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>
```

I also assume that the same issue also occurs in the original sparklr application (which is spring oauth2 sample app) configuration for token request which is very similar. That can be found in  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml, and the related part is below:

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
                authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
                xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
                <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="GET" access="ROLE_DENY" />
                <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="PUT" access="ROLE_DENY" />
                <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="DELETE" access="ROLE_DENY" />
                <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
                <anonymous enabled="false" />
                <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
                <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request
                        parameters -->
                <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
                <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        </http>
```

I would expect spring oauth2 to more appropriately interact with spring security instead of having to put unnecessary and misleading configuration, and that makes me think that I may have missed something. Since security is a sensitive aspect I wanted to share that with you and ask if my conclusion correct.

Comment: Why don't you report this to the Spring forum?

Comment: What is version you are using, there is new version coming out did you check the same on new version http://spring.io/blog/2014/04/18/spring-security-oauth-2-0-0-rc1-available

Answer (score 11):

The /oauth/token provides two different ways to authenticate clients which are requesting tokens:

- Using HTTP-Basic authentication (when "http-basic" element is present)

  The authentication is handled with org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter and processes the "Authorization" HTTP header which contains base64 encoded credentials of the client. The filter only performs processing when the Authorization header is present. This method is always tried first. The entry point defined on http-basic will only be invoked when user has supplied an "Authorization" header with invalid content - that's why you don't see the entry point invoked in your debugger, try to set an Authorization HTTP header and your breakpoint will get a hit.
- As defined in the OAuth standard using client_id and client_secret HTTP paremeters

  This is handled using org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter and by default uses entry point which sends back WWW-Authenticate header to the client. The default entry point can be customized (there's a setAuthenticationEntryPoint method). The entry point is only used when you supply client_id parameter.

Both of these methods use different ways to obtain client's username+password, but verify it against the same authentication manager.

The "No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established" error which you observe when taking out the <http-basic> element is coming from Spring Security itself, not from the OAuth Extension. The reason is that Spring Security is not able to tell that there's a default entry point already configured inside of the custom filter ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter. And the HTTP configuration of Spring Security always must have at least one entry point available.

So, the complete logic goes as follows:

- when you include "Authorization" header with invalid credentials and <http-basic> element is present , system will use entry point defined on the <http-basic> element. If none is specified (attribute entry-point-ref is missing), system will create a default instance of BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint automatically for you and use it.
- when you include HTTP parameter "client_id" and "client_secret" with invalid credentials and custom filter clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter is present, system will use entry point defined in the clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter bean (which is by default instance of OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint)
- in case neither "Authorization" header nor "client_id" parameter are present and the endpoint requires authentication ("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"), system will use the entry point defined on the <http entry-point-ref="">, if present, otherwise it will use the entry point defined on the http-basic (as above)
- in case you don't specify neither http-basic (or other default authentication method which Spring recognizes), nor default entry point using the <http entry-point-ref="">, system will fail with "No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established", because it requires at least one entry point and it doesn't understand that there's one available inside the clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter.

Regarding your observations:

> >> The basic filter is not used and can be removed, if we specify the
>   endpoint in the http namespace instead.

> This is true in case you are authentication your clients using client_id + client_secret

> >> Specifying either a basic filter,or an endpoint in http namespace is
>   needed only for the compiler to stop the warning. They have no
>   practical use, and the endpoint used is hardcoded inside
>   ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter.

> Partly true, as the entry point will be used in case client_id is missing.

The configuration is indeed confusing (which is partly caused by the fact that OAuth isn't a native part of Spring Security, but an extension), but all of those settings make sense and are used in specific situations.

The changes you made have no security implications.

Comment: it is 4 grant types not 2 {code,implicit,password and client credential}

Comment: The answer isn't dealing with grant types (= mechanisms for obtaining of access tokens), but with client authentication (= how to authenticate clients to the authorization server). Client authentication can be part of authorization code, resource owner and client credentials grant (+ e.g. assertion grant type). For the implicit grant type specification explicitly states that "when issuing an access token during the implicit grant flow, the authorization server does not authenticate the client". See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.3 for details.

Comment: Hello @VladimírSchäfer, you anser is really good. I am also stuck with, this type of problem, still, i am not able to figure out, what would happen.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930830/oauth2-and-spring-security-fail-on-authentication-using-oauth2-and-spring-secur, in this link, where i define my problme. please help me.